# Как вызвать UIPickerView при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Каким образом я могу вызвать `PickerView` при клике на кнопку?

Comment: Добавьте больше информации, pickerView это тотже самый view. Как вы хотите что-бы он появлялся?

Comment: допустим как `popup`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте [ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0). Здесь я приведу краткое описание версии 2.3.0 данной библиотеки.

Подключение к проекту ActionSheetPicker-3.0 описано по вышеуказанной ссылке. Если Вы пользуетесь CocoaPods, то просто скопируйте строчку `pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0'` в Ваш Podfile. Затем добавьте `import ActionSheetPicker_3_0` в необходимый файл с Вашим кодом, и тогда Вы сможете показать `UIPickerView` вот так (код для Swift 4.2/Xcode 10.1):

```
let rows = [
    ["Первый столбец, первая строка", "Первый столбец, вторая строка"],
    ["Второй столбец, первая строка", "Второй столбец, вторая строка"]
]
let initialSelection = [1, 1]
ActionSheetMultipleStringPicker.show(withTitle: "Заголовок",
                                     rows: rows,
                                     initialSelection: initialSelection,
                                     doneBlock: { picker, indexes, values in
    return
}, cancel: { _ in
    return
}, origin: self.view)
```

В качестве значения параметра `origin` следует передавать объект класса `UIBarButtonItem` или `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

создайте в контроллере textField, pickerView, button

```
lazy var pickerView:UIPickerView = {
    let picker = UIPickerView()
    picker.contentMode = .bottom
    picker.dataSource = self
    picker.delegate = self
    return picker
}()

lazy var textField:UITextField! = {
    let textField = UITextField()
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.inputView = pickerView
    textField.isHidden = true
    view.addSubview(textField)
    
    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Готово", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneActionTolBar(_:)))
    let flexSpase = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    toolBar.setItems([flexSpase, doneButton], animated: true)
    textField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    toolBar.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    return textField
}()

lazy var button:UIButton! = {
    let button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle("Фильтр", for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(activetyPicker(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

@objc private func activetyPicker(_ sender:UIButton) {
    textField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

Все! при нажатии кнопки будет появляться pickerView